# Are there any other Gnoll/Hyena related statblocks?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, dnd-adventurers-league

I am planning on building a high-level “Yeenoghian” multi-part epic encounter, using only official material, in the scope of Adventurers League play.

Are there any gnoll/hyena-related statblocks other than the following?

- Gnoll
- Gnoll Hunter
- Gnoll Flesh Gnawer
- Gnoll Pack Lord
- Gnoll Fang of Yeenoghu
- Gnoll Witherling
- Flind
- Hyena
- Giant Hyena
- Shoosuva
- Yeenoghu himself

Related here means that the potentially missing statblock(s) would have a strong link of association with gnolls, hyenas or the Demon Lord Yeenoghu, and/or would physically look similar to either of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed [Gash the gnoll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gash-the-gnoll) (a CR 1/2 NPC) from Out of the Abyss among the creature blocks with the gnoll tag ([D&D Beyond Search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-sub-types=3)).

For creatures with a strong link to gnolls, the section in *Volo's Guide to Monsters* on gnolls includes a subsection on Gnoll Allies (p. 38). They are:

- Demons. In addition to Yeenoghu, the book suggests:

  - [barlguras](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/barlgura)
  - [dretches](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dretch)
  - [hezrous](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/hezrou)
  - [manes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/manes)
  - [maw demons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/maw-demon)
- [Ghouls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ghoul)
- Hyenas (already covered in question)
- [Leucrottas](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/leucrotta)
- [Trolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/troll)
- Also associated with gnolls are [cultist of Yeenoguh](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm/monster-lore#Cultists) which can be any type of humanoid using a variety of statblocks, but maybe in particular [cultists](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/cultist).

Also, Yeenohu's own lil' pupper; [Crokek'toeck](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/crokektoeck) from *Baldur's Gate: Decent into Avernus* (p. 230) deserves a mention. (Thanks Sdjz)

Comment: Ohhh! Leucrottas, that’s a big one !

Comment: I wasn’t aware of Volo’s in depth Section on Gnolls. I just read it. Fascinating stuff !